# PostgreSQL trigger not executing after update

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have created a postgreSQL trigger that dosen't seem to be activating but also isn't throwing an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE cp SET product_found = NEW.product_found
    WHERE cp.id = NEW.id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS y on c;

CREATE TRIGGER y
    AFTER UPDATE ON c
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE x();
Example update below
UPDATE c SET product_found = true WHERE id = 1;
```

I have tried replacing NEW with OLD but whenever i update in the table c product found in table cp is not equal to NEW.product_found which is a boolean.

Comment: 1) Are there other triggers on table `c` or `cp` that could be affecting the result? 2) Add to question example `UPDATE` query to table `c` and the result in table `c` and `cp`.

Comment: There are no other triggers i have added an example update statement below. Thanks

Comment: there seems no problem with your code see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ba8d833878dc1bcd76299cd6696a0258

Comment: You did not include what the results of the query was in tables `c` and `cp`. Is there more then one table named `cp` in the database, in other words in different schemas?

Comment: 1 row affected in 1 table, and no there is only one c and one cp table.

Comment: You need to look at the data to see what happened to it.  The completion tag doesn't tell you what happened inside the trigger (other than if the trigger blocked the update completely).  If you want to know what happened, you need to look.